# How can I find Quota abusers with YouTube Data API v3?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a question about Quotas with the YouTube Data API v3. I have a Windows application written in C# which has many users. I need to find out from the web interface which user is throttling my API Quota via my application. I assume this is possible because I'm passing in unique user ID with each Auth request.

Here is the code I'm using to auth a user (which works fine, however, I need access to the auth.Username parameter from the web interface)

```
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    secrets,
    scopes,
    auth.Username,
    cancelToken,
    dataStore);
```

From the dashboard: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/quotas?project=ProjectID
I see a generic quote for the API key, but no low level info.

I could make calls to my personal server and manage quotes there, but that's more servers calls and I feel this should already be done by the YouTube API, I just can't find the information in the web interface, unless, I'm missing something!

Comment: I think the only way to get what you aim is to audit all the request including the user that made the request. When using the Google console, this will only report traffic of the credential used (not specifying for each user).

Comment: Hi, yes this is currently what I have by default. I hoped quota information would be provided at user-level.